# Importing Bin file in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, tensorflow.js

I have tried adding metro.config.js as

```
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('bin');

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

But still it gives me error of unable to resolve module.

I am working in ML project

MY import code for model.json and shards.bin looks like this

```
    const modelJSON = require('../../../assets/NEWJSON2/model.json');

    const modelWeights = require('../../../assets/group1_shards.bin');

    let model = await tf.loadGraphModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights));
```

Comment: Still problem unresolved ?

Answer (score 3):

Update: I changed my metro config,

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');
module.exports = (async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig();
  const { assetExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;
  return {
    resolver: {
      // Add bin to assetExts
      assetExts: [...assetExts, 'bin'],
    }
  };
})();
```

I imported the json and weights as,

```
      const modelJSON = require('../../../assets/model.json');

      const modelWeights = await require('../../../assets/group1_shards.bin');

      let model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights));
```

Comment: Expo v48 requires a folder from where to get the default config. Also, just in case, I returned the whole default config:

`const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
  const {assetExts} = defaultConfig.resolver;
  return {
    ...defaultConfig,
    resolver: {
      ...defaultConfig.resolver,
      // Add bin to assetExts
      assetExts: [...assetExts, 'bin'],
    }
  };
})();`